# The time complexity of Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

I saw some textbook about the worst-case time complexity of Fibonacci Sequence. However, I have the following question:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Alternatively*, one may observe that, from
$$
T(n)\le 2T(n-1)+c,\qquad n\ge 1,
$$ by dividing by $2^n$ one deduces
$$
\frac{T(n)}{2^n}\le \frac{T(n-1)}{2^{n-1}}+c\cdot\frac{1}{2^n},\qquad n\ge 1,
$$$$
\frac{T(n)}{2^n}- \frac{T(n-1)}{2^{n-1}}\le c\cdot\frac{1}{2^n},\qquad n\ge 1,
$$ then summing from $n=1$ to $n=N$ *terms telescope on the left hand side* giving
$$
\frac{T(N)}{2^N}- \frac{T(0)}{2^{0}}\le c\cdot \sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{2^n}=c \cdot \left(1-\frac1{2^N}\right)
$$ that is

> $$
> T(N)\le c \cdot \left(1-\frac1{2^N}\right)+T(0),\qquad N\ge 1.
> $$